# MVC, Twitter bootstrap modal dynamically loaded from partial via jquery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, partial

I have an MVC Layout that has the standard bootstrap modal div etc (http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals).

On the click of an action link (where the view uses the bootstrap modal layout) I have the following JQuery

## 1

```
 $(".popupDialog").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        
        $('<div></div>').load(this.href, function () {
            $(this).find('#myModal').modal();
        });
    });
```

It doesn't load the modal at all.

If I were to remove the outer div from the standard twitter bootstrap modal and place it in the jquery, i.e.

## 2

```
$(".popupDialog").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        
        $('<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"></div>').load(this.href, function () {                    
            $(this).modal();
        });
    });
```

It works great but obviously I don't want to dynamically load the 1st outer div in jquery as in 2.

I've tried unwrapping the first div in 1 before calling .modal() but still no joy.

Any help would be great!

Comment: So, could you tell me what is the issue do you have in a nutshell? Currently I'm able to open the modal and close it (in 2 ways).

Comment: What are you trying to do with this: `$('<div></div>').html($('#myModal'))`

Comment: Ok so my bad, a fundamental misunderstanding of JQuery.  I assumed $('<div></div>') would load a dynamic div.  I have now put a placeholder div with another id into my markup and used that to load the html into and it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Silly mistake.

After putting a placeholder div into my html markup and using that to load the modal html it works fine.

```
 $(".popup-dialog-link").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $('popup-dialog-modal').load(this.href, function () {
            $(this).find('#myModal').modal();
        });
    });
```